Les essentiels ou les essentielles
Pour un titre de formation, peut-on écrire au pluriel « Les essentielles de la formation » et dans ce cas, n'est-ce pas plutôt au masculin : « Les essentiels de la formation » ?

En tant que substantif, essentiel est masculin et essentiellement au singulier.
Le problème avec le titre souhaité est que L'essentiel de la formation risque de ne pas être compris comme attendu (si tant est qu'on sache ce qui est attendu).
Le mieux serait d'utiliser essentiel comme adjectif et de trouver un nom qui va bien avec ce qu'on présente.

Notions essentielles de la formation.
Principes essentiels de la formation.
Notions essentielles à la formation.
Principes essentiels à la formation.
Techniques essentielles de formation.
etc.


Le titre est ambigu: il s'agit peut-être d'un cours de pédagogie, ou les notions essentielles requises pour bien former les personnes seront exposées?
